# Call different action on checking checkbox than on unchecking

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to call one controller action on checking checkbox and another on unchecking.
That is, I want to call "meeting#create" on checking and "meeting#destroy" on unchecking.

This is signup form where You can sign up for several meetings via checkboxes. On checking the checkbox, the corresponding meeting gets added to an order (practically a cart) and on unchecking, the corresponding meeting gets removed from the order.

How is it possible to call a different action depending on actual status of the check_box_tag?

I'm no professional, so it took me long enough to figure out the options I should supply (the url_for) and I don't  have a clue how to do it conditionally.

Please help!

```
<% @meeting.each do |meeting| %>
 <%= check_box_tag 'checkbox', meeting.id, checked = false, :data => {:remote => true, url: url_for(controller: :order, action: :create, meeting_id: meeting), method: :post}, :class => 'checkbox' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i think you should write 2 ajax script and send request based on `checked` status of checkbox.

Comment: i really like how rails handles ajax because you don't actually have to write any ajax - it's handled automatically. So yes, I'll eventually do it. But if there is any railsy way to do it, i'd rather use that.

Comment: There is no rails way in this case i think. Maybe you can write javascript to change `url` and `method` of `data` attributes of your check box when it checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wrote the ajax script by hand.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox").click(function() {
    var chb = $(this);
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/bookings?meeting_id='+chb.attr('value'),
        type: "post"
      });
    }
    else{
     $.ajax({
      url: '/bookings?meeting_id='+chb.attr('value')+'&cart_id='+currentcartid,
      type: "delete"
    });
   };
 });
});
```

One ajax script sufficed.